# green's theorem relating to calculating area

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

[image: http://imgur.com/J8QUiAt]

In this problem, I have to find the area of that blob. Pretty much I have to see if $\,N_x-M_y\,$ is equal to $1$. For the first choice, it **is** equal to $1$, yet the answer key says it is $4$?

Comment: You're correct.

Comment: So it has to be 1? teacher must have messed up

Comment: Yes, apparently so. ;-))